# sql-server detect parents in parent child hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm implementing a recyclebin function in my project. If a whole folder is deleted I would like to see only the folder name and not all of its children (content). Here is how it might look:

`+----+----------+---------------+
    | ID | ParentID | Name          |
    +----+----------+---------------+
    | 3  | 1        | Css           |
    +----+----------+---------------+
    | 4  | 8        | New File.txt  |
    +----+----------+---------------+
    | 6  | 10       | Scripts.js    |
    +----+----------+---------------+
    | 7  | 3        | Styles.css    |
    +----+----------+---------------+
    | 8  | 3        | Bootstrap.css |
    +----+----------+---------------+`

The only output I would like is row 3 and 6.

As you see there is no logical pattern in the Parent-Child relationships, hence it's difficult for me to figure out how to not display child rows.

Another alternative could be to label the rows, then I can sort my output later. For example, like this:

`+----+----------+---------------+--------+
    | ID | ParentID | Name          | Label  |
    +----+----------+---------------+--------+
    | 3  | 1        | Css           | parent |
    +----+----------+---------------+--------+
    | 4  | 8        | New File.txt  | child  |
    +----+----------+---------------+--------+
    | 6  | 10       | Scripts.js    | parent |
    +----+----------+---------------+--------+
    | 7  | 3        | Styles.css    | child  |
    +----+----------+---------------+--------+
    | 8  | 3        | Bootstrap.css | child  |
    +----+----------+---------------+--------+`

Comment: What have you tried so far to resolve this problem? There's quite a few examples on Stack Overflow on querying parent/child tables; for example by using a rCTE (recursive Common Table Expression). Did you have a look at any of the suggested duplicates when you wrote your question? Likely one of them had the answer you were after.

Answer (score 5):

What you want to do is select anything in the recycle bin that doesn't have a parent.

```
Select child.ID,child.ParentID,child.Name from [table] child 
left join [table] parent
on child.parentID = parent.ID
where parent.ID is null
```

This will get anything whose parent is not in the table

Comment: Not quite... I would like to select anything but the children --> Parents only...

Comment: That is what that does select anything that there is no parent in the current table did you actually try it?